# Restore and delete file on Google Drive by service account

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-python-client, service-accounts

I created a file in shared folder on Google Drive by service account.

Here, my code to create/upload file:

```
from dataclasses import fields
from googleapiclient import discovery
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

scope = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
            filename="my-key.json", scopes=scope
)

try:
        # create gmail api client
        service = discovery.build("drive", "v3", credentials=credentials)
        file_metadata = {
            'title': 'My Report',
            'mimeType': 'application/zip',
            'parents': ['folder_id'],
            'name': 'test'

        }
        media = MediaFileUpload('test.zip', mimetype='application/zip',resumable=True)
        # pylint: disable=maybe-no-member
        file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()
        print(F'File with ID: "{file.get("id")}" has been uploaded.')

except HttpError as error:
    print(F'An error occurred: {error}')
    file = None
```

Then a few people in shared folder deleted file by their user account. Here, problem is that `usage` of `storageQuota` is not reset:

```
storageQuota: {
   "limit":"16106127360",
   "usage":"9746694095",
   "usageInDrive":"9746694095",
   "usageInDriveTrash":"0"
}
```

In addition, i forgot `file_id` that user deleted.

Is there a way for me to restore and delete that file by service account?

Comment: Do a file.list with the service account.  The file is still there some where.

Comment: Thanks your replying! Yes. I used file.list by service account but it's not there.

Comment: If the file isnt in trashed then you cant undelete it.  As for the space issue 1. Make sure the storage quota you are showing is that of the service account. 2. do a about.get.  do a file.list again with the service account if the storage still doesn't match up then i would post it as a bug [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191650%2B)

Comment: Yes, file isn't in trashed. Above storage quota that i get from about.get from service account. Yes, i used file.list many times to check.

Comment: When utilizing the "file.list" are you adding the parameter "trashed=true"? If that is the case, it might have been moved to another shared drive, can you check the audit logs from the Admin console from movements based on the shared drive ID.